# What does "write the bill with a ‘double meat ax’" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

What does *writing the bill with a "double meat ax"* mean?

I found the phrase *double meat ax* in today's *Washington Post* article, [House approves dramatic cuts in federal spending in 235-189 vote](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2011/02/19/AR2011021900503_pf.html), dealing with last night's House vote on drastic federal budget cuts.

I know the meaning of *double ax* as a double-bladed ax, but I don't know *double meat ax*, and why the phrase was used with quotation marks, which suggests the writer used the phrase with special implication. Can you tell me exactly what *writing the bill with a "double meat ax"* means? The text reads:

> During the bleary-eyed final roll call at 4:35 a.m., 235 Republicans were joined by no Democrats in support of dramatic spending reductions that they said were needed to address a soaring annual deficit of $1.6 trillion; 189 Democrats—as well as three Republicans—opposed it, accusing Republicans of writing the bill with a "double meat ax."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going after something "with a meat axe" means going at it very crudely and vigorously, with an intention to do great damage. To call it here a "double meat axe" means the Republicans intend to cut the budget drastically, without looking at any of the particulars very closely.

Should your doctor ever diagnose you with a pre-cancerous mole or a cyst, and then suggest a surgeon should attack it "with a meat axe," it would be a good idea to find another doctor.

Oh, and this would be a good time to compare the statement with the expression you taught me: 鶏を割くに牛刀を用いる (to cut a chicken with a butcher's knife).

Comment: Robusto-san. Thank you for your kind and quick answer as always. I know both words of ‘double ax’ and ‘meat ax,’ but I heard the word ‘double meat ax’ for the first time. Is it a compositive word of ‘double ax’ and ‘meat ax,’ meaning a drastic chop of budget – 大なたを振るう- a counterpart in Japanese?

Comment: Robusto-san. By a compositive word, I mean a compositive word coined by the writer, or it's a well-worn word?

Comment: Oishi-san: To use a "meat axe" on something is a familiar expression in English. It's not original with the writer.

Comment: And it doesn't have anything to do with "double axe" ... It's "double" plus "meat axe".

Comment: Robusto-san. I know meat axe is a familiar word. But Malvoloo says there is no such a thing as 'double-bladed meat axe.'

Comment: Robusto-san. I know meat axe is a familiar word. And you say 'double meat axe' is not the writer's coinage. Malvolo says there is no such a thing as 'double-bladed meat axe.' I'm confused.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: Oishi-san, Malvolio is correct that there is no such thing as a double-bladed meat axe. And if you look again, you'll see that I said "To use a 'meat axe' on something" is a familiar expression, not that "double meat axe" is a genuine artifact. "Double" is used here as an intensifier. The expression takes "meat axe" (familiar) and multiplies it by two. The writer is just trying to make the cliché twice as strong with the word double. He might as well have said "giant meat axe" or some other such descriptor. But he did not mean a literal double-bladed meat axe.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, that is some bad writing.  "With a meat-axe" is a cliché (I almost wrote "a tired cliché", which would be quite autological) and the writer tried, and failed, to enliven it by adding "double" (from "double-bladed axe", but there's no such thing as a double-bladed meat-axe).  Then depressed by his failure there (or elated by a false sense of success), he proceeded to mix the metaphor in with "write".

The [takeaway](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13287/what-does-may-that-not-be-the-takeaway-of-this-speech-mean-in-salah-palins-moc) in this is, when you find yourself using a cliché, just *stop*.  Express yourself in some entirely different (ideally metaphor-free) way.  Do not try to "freshen" the phrase, "spice it up", "put a new spin on it".  You'd just be flogging a dead, uh, Clydesdale...

Comment: Two answers don't seem to be consistent. Is there any other opinions about appropreateness of the word 'double meat axe'?

Answer (score 0):

A *meat axe* is the double-handed blade slaughtermen use to hack carcasses in half, so probably the least subtle tool in existence.  So far, so good (though rather a tired metaphor).  But there's no such thing as a double meat axe, and "write" just turns it from a metaphor into a blurred simile.  So no, I can't tell you exactly what the phrase means, and I don't believe anybody else can either: certainly not the original writer.

Answer (score 0):

Using two meat axes (not some mythical double-bladed one).  Apparently how the Democrats (not professional writers) described the Republicans' hacking away at the budget with extreme violence.